# How to show more data in lower zoom levels with Vector tiles

Tags: leaflet, vector, vector-tiles, zoom, openmaptiles

I have downloaded OpenMapTiles Vector .mbtiles file for whole world data ~50GB, created a localhost to serve .pbf tiles and rendering them on client with maplibre-gl. At zoom level 12, minor roads are displayed, see image:

[image: Zoom 12 Minor Roads visible]

But on Zoom 11 Minor Roads are invisible and map looks a bit empty.
[image: Zoom 11 Minor Roads Invisible]

I would like to have minor roads also displayed on Zoom 11, and Zoom 10 even.

I have tried to display this mbtiles file in QGIS as well and it is the same, on Zoom 11 minor roads are not displayed so I suppose that there is no info about minor roads in those .pbf tiles that are generated on Zoom 11.
Is there a way to somehow add that data from Zoom 12 to Zoom 11, or any other way to make this happen?

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.